# SSE echo from PHP duplicating at random intervals

Tags: php, mysql, server-sent-events

I'm trying to set up a PHP server send event, which works okay. But at random intervals it is pushing the same data repeatedly.

Here's a quick scenario to clarify what I'm describing: Let's say I insert a db record at 1:00:00. The record's data is pushed as it should. However, at 1:03:00 that record's data is pushed a second time. Then at 1:03:17, it is pushed again. And I now have 3 instances of the record displayed.

Why is this happening, and why at random intervals?

I increased php execution time, but the issue is still occurring.

In the browser console, I'm getting this error: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

I have this for client side:

```
  <script>
    var source = new EventSource('pdo_updates.php');
    var pdo_updates;
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
        pdo_updates = e.lastEventId + '' + e.data + '<br>';
        document.getElementById("videoID").innerHTML += pdo_updates;
    };
    evtSource.close();
  </script>
```

And this for server side:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
function send_msg($id, $msg) {
    echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
    $last_event_id = floatval(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] : False);
    if ($last_event_id == 0) {
        $last_event_id = floatval(isset($_GET["lastEventId"]) ? $_GET["lastEventId"] : False);
    }

    $last_id = 0;
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

        while(1) {
            $id  = $last_event_id != False ? $last_event_id : $last_id;
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, message FROM messages WHERE id > :id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $result = $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
            $stmt->bindValue('id', $id);

            if ($result) {
                while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    if ($data) {
                        send_msg($data['id'], $data['message']);
                        $last_id = $data['id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            sleep(1);
        }       
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: I guess that `pdo_updates.php` after tot. seconds reach the maximum execution time, a fatal error appears, and the client try to reconnect to it with an old `last_event_id`..?

Comment: You're probably righ -->PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\Project\\Youtubeplayer\\pdo_updates.php on line 26 ----
How do I correct this? SSE by nature, depends on a persistent connection. Nevermind: http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set

Comment: Increasing execution timeout hasn't helped. Here is an error from the browser console: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after trying just about every keepalive related header, and every apache timeout adjustment config, I ended up running a packet capture. I discovered there was a TCP reset was being triggered by the remote end. I have my site behind Cloudflare, and once I disabled Cloudflare the issue *partially* disappeared. The TCP session was being refreshed every 100 seconds and would cause the last message to appear again when that happened. This was responsible for the browser console error: `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

At the same time, however, there was an issue in my submit code. But I'm not 100% sure why.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#submitmessage").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
```

> ```
>          $("#myvideo").val("");
> ```

```
       }
     });
```

I needed to clear the value in my input field after submit. I haven't had any duplicates since.

Comment: Had the same problem with my load balancer on AWS. Increasing the timeout fixed it for me.